# how to check player states of all rinning apps in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How to check that no one app is recording audio?

```
public void playerUpdate(Player arg0, String arg1, Object arg2)
{
     add(new RichTextField(formattedDate + ": "  + arg1 ));
}
```

this function and `p.getState()` returns the state of current application player only.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [prefetch()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#prefetch%28%29) which will throw a [MediaException](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/MediaException.html) if any other application is using the player already